# Uploading files to S3 bucket using access key and secret access key- IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, curl, amazon-s3

How can i upload files to s3 bucket from iOS app using swift using static credentials(access key and secret access key). I have tried the amplify guide, but i am not unable to generate the json file, when i tried to configure it i got this error

*UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.*

but i am able to upload files using a bash script(curl), when i tried to replicate the same, i am seeing the below error, i am fine with implementing using the below method for now instead of using AWS amplify library, whichever works first

*The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.*

Below is the working bash script,

```
file_to_upload=card.jpg
bucket=dash-poc
filepath="/${bucket}/${file_to_upload}"
contentType="image/jpeg"
dateValue=`date -R`
signature_string="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${filepath}"
signature_hash=`echo -en ${signature_string} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3_secret_key} -binary | base64`
# actual curl command to do PUT operation on s3
echo $signature_hash
curl -v -X PUT -T "${file_to_upload}" \
  -H "Host: *********.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3_access_key}:${signature_hash}" \
  https://**********.com/dash-poc/card.jpg
```

EDIT:
for v4 Signing

```
 func signS3RequestV4(urlRequest : NSMutableURLRequest, credentials: AWSCredentials) -> String{
    let awsEndpoint = AWSEndpoint(region: .EUWest2, serviceName: "s3", url: URL(string: "******.com/")!)

            urlRequest.setValue(awsEndpoint!.hostName, forHTTPHeaderField: "host")
            
            let date = Date()
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = AWSDateISO8601DateFormat2
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
            let dateStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            urlRequest.setValue(dateStamp, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-amz-date")
            
            let dateFormatterShort = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatterShort.dateFormat = AWSDateShortDateFormat1
            let dateStampShort = dateFormatterShort.string(from: date)
        
            let scope = String(format: "%@/%@/%@/%@", dateStampShort, awsEndpoint!.regionName, (awsEndpoint?.serviceName)!, AWSSignatureV4Terminator)
            let signingCredentials = String(format: "%@/%@", credentials.accessKey, scope)
            
            let httpMethod = urlRequest.httpMethod
            let path = urlRequest.url!.path
            let query = urlRequest.url?.query ?? ""
            
            let contentSha256 = AWSSignatureSignerUtility.hexEncode(String(data: AWSSignatureSignerUtility.hash(urlRequest.httpBody), encoding: String.Encoding.ascii))
            urlRequest.setValue(contentSha256, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-amz-content-sha256")
            
            let headers = urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields
            let canonicalRequest = AWSSignatureV4Signer.getCanonicalizedRequest(httpMethod, path: path, query: query, headers: headers, contentSha256: contentSha256)
            
            let stringToSign = String(format: "%@\n%@\n%@\n%@",
                                      AWSSignatureV4Algorithm,
                                      urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "x-amz-date")!,
                                      scope, AWSSignatureSignerUtility.hexEncode(AWSSignatureSignerUtility.hashString(canonicalRequest)))
            print("AWS4 String to Sign \(stringToSign)")
            
            let kSigning = AWSSignatureV4Signer.getV4DerivedKey(credentials.secretKey, date: dateStampShort, region: awsEndpoint?.regionName, service: awsEndpoint?.serviceName)
            
            let signature = AWSSignatureSignerUtility.sha256HMac(with: stringToSign.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), withKey: kSigning)
        let signatureString = AWSSignatureSignerUtility.hexEncode(String(data: signature, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii))
            let authorization = String(format: "%@ Credential=%@, SignedHeaders=%@, Signature=%@",
                AWSSignatureV4Algorithm,
                signingCredentials,
                AWSSignatureV4Signer.getSignedHeadersString(headers), signatureString)
            
            return authorization
        }
```

Kindly guide me through this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's an [AWS Swift SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/aws-sdk-swift-developer-preview/) that hides this complexity from you. But if you want to continue with low-level HTTP API, then review [v4 signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html).

Comment: @jarmod yes i tried to do v4 signing, i have added the function in my question, but i still see signature mismatch error

Comment: Signing issues are very common (hence the value of the SDK) but if you want to DIY sign then all I can propose is that you read the docs very carefully and/or you investigate the dozens of other posts from developers struggling with request signing.

Comment: @jarmod yes i read a lot of posts about developers facing issues with v4 signing, now i am trying with AWS swift SDK, so i notice that the SDK on its own prepends the bucket name i provided in front of the URL which i dont want to, basically i have this S3 hosted on IBM cloud storage, i did read about Virtual host style and path style(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html) but i dont see how can i configure them in my SDK, you have any idea on that?

Comment: It may be the case that the Swift SDK doesn't expose [path-style](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/843). In case it's helpful, here's Python code to manually build an [IBM cloud storage pre-signed URL](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/cloud-archive/2018/11/create-a-presigned-url-to-download-an-object-in-python-3-x/), in case comparing it to your code is helpful.

Comment: @jarmod sorry for the delayed reply, sure i will take a look at it the python implementation, i will be back with an update on how it goes.